# Google+ plus post with video embedded via PHP

Tags: google-plus

I want to share a link on google+ which will have embedded video when shared as post

Here are the relevant open graph tags that are being used

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://mysiteurl" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://imageurl" />
<meta property="og:description" content="desc goes here /> 
<meta property="og:title" content="title goes here" /> 
<meta property="og:site_name" content="sitename" />
<meta property="og:video" content="https://www.youtube.com/v/XXXXXX" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="300" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="200" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />'
```

I am using

```
<a title="Google plus" href='https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmysiteurl'><img src='/images/googleshare.png'></a>
```

for sharing via php.

Google plus is picking everything from open graph except video. Do I need to do something else to share this link with video embedded?

Answer (score 1):

Google+ has a small whitelist of sites they embed video from. You are not on the whitelist so video previews won't work. Google does not have a formal process for getting on the whitelist.